# setPadding() on Button programmatically not working

Tags: android, android-layout, button

When I set padding on a button using XML it works without problems.

**XML for the button:**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/comment_video"
    android:layout_below="@+id/input_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/comment_video"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

**Screenshot of button:**

[image]

Then when I do it programmatically it's not working.

**Code for the button:**

```
// Add reply button
final Button replyButton = new Button(mContext);
replyButton.setId(170000 + i2);
replyButton.setText("REPLY");
replyButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
replyButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C70000"));
replyButton.setPadding(dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px);
replyButton.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 14);
replyButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp8 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp8.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, textInputLayout.getId());
lp8.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_END, relativeLayout3.getId());
lp8.setMargins(0, dp4_in_px, dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px);
replyButton.setLayoutParams(lp8);
```

**Screenshot of button:**

[image]

I set thousands of views dynamically based on YouTube data and must do it programmatically, at least as far as I know.

The formula used for variables in setPadding and setMargin are as follows:

```
int dp4 = 4;  // 4 dps
final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
int dp4_in_px = (int) (dp4 * scale + 0.5f);
int dp10 = 10;  // 10 dps
int dp10_in_px = (int) (dp10 * scale + 0.5f);
```

Any help is appreciated.

**Update 1 - Screenshot of layout bounds**

[image]

**Update 2 - Sharp corners**

Another small detail that might be a clue. The corners on the programmatically made button is sharp. Normally they're a bit rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, with help from war_Hero in comments I've found the solution.

setBackgroundColor() don't work. It sets the entire background, including the padding, to the same color.

This:

```
replyButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C70000"));
```

Should be replaced with something like this:

```
replyButton.getBackground().setColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(mContext, R.color.colorAccent), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
replyButton.setPadding(dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px, dp10_in_px);
```

you should replace line something like this

```
 replyButton.setPadding(0,padding,0,0);
```